# docker run -i and /dev/stdin

Tags: bash, docker, stdin

I am trying to make a wrapper for docker run (docker exec actually, but docker run makes a better example) that you can pipe data into if you want.

The wrapper works like this:

```
$ cat cat.sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash
docker run -i ubuntu:14.04 cat $@ < /dev/stdin
```

The funny thing is that if make another scirpt that calls this script, and then pipe something into the script the parent script, the child script reads it!

Here are the details:

When I explicitly pipe something into `cat.sh` with this script it does what I thought it would do.

```
$ cat example2.sh 
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -e
echo OK | ./cat.sh
echo now show the stuff that was piped into _this_ program
cat < /dev/stdin

$ echo this is a test | ./example2.sh 
OK
now show the stuff that was piped into _this_ program
this is a test
```

However, when I don't pipe anything into `cat.sh`, it doesn't do what I thought it would.

```
$ cat example1.sh 
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -e
./cat.sh etc/timezone
echo now show the stuff that was piped into _this_ program
cat < /dev/stdin

$ echo this is a test | ./example1.sh 
Etc/UTC
now show the stuff that was piped into _this_ program
```

I thought I would see this

```
$ echo this is a test | ./example1.sh 
Etc/UTC
now show the stuff that was piped into _this_ program
this is a test
```

When I remove `-i` from `docker run`, `example1.sh` works as I had hoped, but `example2.sh` doesn't.

When I replace `docker run -i ubuntu:14.04 cat $@ < /dev/stdin` with `cat $@ < /dev/stdin` everything works as expected as well.

What is `-i` doing that is allowing it to read a parent program's stdin?
Is there a way to reproduce this without docker?

Is there a way to write `cat.sh` so that it will pipe stdin to `docker run` when something is specifically piped to it, but won't read what has been piped into the parent program?

Comment: I amazed that people still write such things in bash: here what you would need to do have you written it in Go, in which docker itself is written: `pa := os.ProcAttr{Files: []*os.File{os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr}}` followed by `proc, err := os.StartProcess(name, argv, &pa)` and followed by `state, err := proc.Wait()`. 3 lines plus error handling and a clean binary for the job.

Comment: The `< /dev/stdin` isn't necessary; `cat` inherits its standard input from the calling script by default.